# Simple harmonic motion of a cylinder inside another cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

[image]

Hi guys! One quick note before diving into the question. When you are answering this question please consider me as a layman and be as thorough as possible.

So, I have 2 cylinders; the smaller one rotating, without slipping, inside the larger one. I need to calculate the period of oscillation of the small cylinder. The larger cylinder has a negligible width and the smaller one is a solid cylinder. The position of the smaller cylinder before oscillation is such that, its centre of mass is $\theta$ degrees away from the mean position and point A will cover an angle $\alpha$ when it reaches the centre. I am not familiar with moment of inertia so please describe why you use a certain value for the moment of inertia when you are using it in your calculation.

Also if you can, please mention any two materials (for the construction of the two cylinders) which would be suitable when practically conducting the experiment.

Comment: Welcome to phy.stackexchange! It will help people to answer your question if you post some of the steps you’ve already tried in solving this problem.

Comment: Hi, @DavidH. I tried to equate both the expressions for velocity to arrive at the final result. $$ \frac{d\alpha}{dt}*r = \frac{d\theta}{dt}*(R-r)$$ Then I took the double derivate with respect to time. $$ \frac{d^2\alpha}{dt^2}*r = \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}*(R-r) $$ So the angular acceleration of the smaller cylinder is: $$\frac{d^2\alpha}{dt^2} =  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}*\frac{(R-r)}{r} $$ So, $$ I*\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}*\frac{(R-r)}{r} = -mgsin(\theta)*\phi $$ Now, I don't know what values I should use for the moment of intertia (I) and angular displacement (phi).

Comment: @SamyakJain: incorporate your calc in your question, not in the comment section, please.

Answer (score 1):

As this is clearly a homework-style question, I'll only point you in the right direction. The actual calculations I leave to you.

The easiest path here, assuming your ensemble contains conservative forces only, is by means of *Conservation of Energy*:

$$T=U+K$$

where $T$ is system *total energy* (or Hamiltonian, a $\text{constant}$), $U$ is system *potential energy* and $K$ is system *kinetic energy*.

Taking the time derivative:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}$$

of both sides then yields the *Newtonian Equation of Motion*.

Calculating $U$ is easy: just choose a relevant reference point for $U=0$.

For $K$, bear in mind that there is *rotational* $K_R$ as well as *translational* $K_T$ in play. You need to calculate both: $K=K_R+K_T$. Also we assume *rolling without slipping*, so:

$$v=\omega R$$

which will allow you to express everything as $\dot{\theta}=\omega$. Time derivation will then give you an expression for $\ddot{\theta}$.

> Also if you can, please mention any two materials (for the
> construction of the two cylinders) which would be suitable when
> practically conducting the experiment.

For the outer cylinder, strength would be most important and for the inner one 'solidity', i.e. something dense like steel, IMO.

Comment: in mechanical engineering dynamics, this is known as the "cigar tube problem". You want the inner surface of the big tube to be coated with a thin layer of rubber sheet to ensure the smaller tube rolls without slippage.

Answer (score 0):

In your last equation, if you set  ϕ = r, the equation expresses torque and angular acceleration about the instantaneous axis of rotation at the point of contact.  The, I, would be $.5mr^2$ for rotation about the center of mass plus $mr^2$ for the motion of the CM.  For small values of θ, you replace sinθ with θ. Remembering that the angular acceleration = -$ω^2$ times θ then $ω^2$ (the angular frequency) = g/(1.5(R - r))